# Proof that the number of involutions in $S_n$ is odd.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, involutions

We know that an involution is any permutation $\pi$ such that $\pi^2=id$.

We also know that the number of involutions of $S_n$ will be the number of permutations $\pi\in S_n$ such that $\pi$ has order $2.$

But can you prove that this number will always be odd?

Comment: The number of involutions in any finite group of even order is odd. It is probably easier to prove that!

Comment: Your two definitions of involution are inconsistent. Note that $\{\pi \in S_2: \pi^2 = id\} = S_2$ has size $2$...